# github Page build failure: timeout

Tags: github, timeout, jekyll, github-pages

I've been trying to push my [code](https://github.com/lindenb/jvarkit) to github for 24H00.  Everytime, I receive the following message  ( https://github.com/lindenb/jvarkit/runs/352148142 )

> The page build failed for the `master` branch with the following error:
>
> Page build timed out. 
>   Please try again later. For more information, see https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/troubleshooting-jekyll-build-errors-for-github-pages-sites#troubleshooting-build-errors.

unless I'm wrong, there is no indication errors like 'timeout' in the URLs above.  Furthermore, the [github status](https://www.githubstatus.com/) is ok.

The pages are compiled from a [docs](https://github.com/lindenb/jvarkit/tree/master/docs) directory: it contains  348 files   (2.5 M). The pages used to be quickly compiled before I added a new file in docs/

How can I fix this problem ? Where can I find any indication about the quotas (time / size) for the github pages ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to contact GtHub Support for a detailed log on the error? This could be entirely unrelated to your site's contents..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message was misleading.

There was just an error in the markdown format (backticks missing in a code section).